# Is it possible to manual ack with Masstransit

Tags: masstransit

Due to some reasons, we're not allowed to use more than one queue for our LOB.

So, we have set a very large prefetch number, and the consumer of that single queue will be in charge of dispatching to other in memory queues according to some message properties. Other background tasks will fetch the message from the in memory queues and handle it.

To avoid loss of messages, is it possible to manual ack the message until the background task finishes handling the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MassTransit handles message acknowledgement, there is no way to work around it. Once the message consumer completes, it will be acknowledged. Messages remain in the queue until they are acknowledged. There is no way messages could be lost using this approach.

> Also, your approach of using a single transport queue and then having a bunch of in-memory queues is an incredibly poor (terrible, horrible, worst possible thing ever perhaps) design choice due to a really bad rule about queue usage. MassTransit can actually do all of that dispatch for you with multiple consumers on the receive endpoint for the various message types. But a single queue is still a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Sometime manual ack is very handy, consider a situation where you consume message from the queue, and you want to do some work and if it succeeded you ack the message, otherwise it stays in the queue. We could debate that if something goes wrong, we may republish/resend the message, but that itself may fail, leaving the message lost without proper processing.

Comment: MassTransit has plenty of other facilities for such things, no reason to worry about ack/nak at that level.

Comment: The only capability missing here compared to technologies like Spring Cloud Stream in the Java world is the notion that a given message could have three, not two possible outcomes. SCSt supports Accept, Reject, and Requeue for each message, allowing to differentiate between a "bad message" and a "cannot process right now" message.